# Is there a difference between these device terms?

Tags: data-acquisition

Is the term "[High-Speed Digitizer](https://www.keysight.com/en/pc-1128783/High-Speed-Digitizers-and-Multichannel-Data-Acquisition-Solution?cc=US&lc=eng)" same as saying "data acquisition device with high sampling rate"?

The definiton I encounter for a digitizer is: " A digitizer is a hardware device that receives analog information, such as sound or light, and records it digitally"

But some companies insists on using both terms which makes me confused. Can we say a digitizer is exactly the same thing with data-acquisition hardware? Synonyms?

Comment: You are only going to get opinions on this. So, to turn this into a proper question, state why you want to know - is it so that you can use the correct terms when searching for something?

Comment: It is because I don't want to use the wrong term. From your words I think that they are indeed same things. (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrical engineering (and most types of engineering really) don't have a big book of 'ye old definitions'. Not only do different people use different definitions, sometimes definition will change based on context.

For an automated-test designer, a digitizer will probably be a device that takes an analog waveform and turns it into a digital stream of bits. (the key that separates them from oscilloscopes is that they are usually continuous, instead of triggered-bursts which is what scopes do). This would be similar to what you show from the Keysight page.

For people doing something like structural analysis of a mechanical structure, a digitizer might include a bunch of sensors too.

For an artist, a digitizer is a device that allows them to scan images or books into a digital format.

This is also why books in the field of engineering will generally clearly define important terms so there is no confusion about them.